# Unable to get json from google distance matrix api

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to make a jQuery $.ajax call to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API , but this doesn't work because of cross-domain security issues.

I am using the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
         url: 
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='+start+'&destinations='+end+'&key=MY_KEY',
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         crossDomain: true,
         success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
         }.bind(this),      
         error: function(xhr, status, err) {
           console.error('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='+start+'&destinations='+end+'&key=MY_KEY', status, err.toString());
         }.bind(this)
       });
```

**I am getting the following error :**

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=delhi&destinations=jaipur&key=MY_KEY. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have read almost all the possible solutions for fixing this.
even tried changing dataType: 'jsonp', but it dosent work for me. **On changing the datatype to 'jsonp' im getting the following parse error.**

parsererror Error: jQuery18208230966408134822_1475687832399 was not called

Can somebody please help me fix it.Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this javascript? Are you using a local server? Sidenote, even if its not super important its generally not a good idea to post your key for the world to see.

Comment: oh ok... ya im using localhost

Comment: Im using node-static server currently.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: You can use jsonp - this will fix the request, however the response will come back with syntax errors because it's clean json. If you're reading this, I gave up, and just downloaded Google's whole API for a single request (ridiculous...)